# Redirect back to location after being redirected to login

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity-2

I'm in an ASP.NET 4.6 Web Forms application.

I am trying to use claims to check if a user is authorized to payroll page like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ContainsClaim(User.Identity.Name, "role", "admin"))
        {
            //execute function 1
            Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx");
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsClaim(string userName, string claimType, string claimValue)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = context.Users.Where(s => s.UserName == "rsadmin").FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return user.Claims.Where(s => s.ClaimType == claimType && s.ClaimValue == claimValue).Count() > 0;
    }
```

A payroll user clicked on the payroll page before logging in. So she got redirected to login page. How can I automatically direct them back to payroll page after logging in?

Comment: I you would use the "normal" detection of authenticated users, aspnet redirects you to the login page with the previous page as a `returnUrl` querystring parameter. But you could add it to the redirect yourself, check for it after login and redirect the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.

You can use a query parameter for returnUrl which you can use to redirect upon login. If you do use a query parameter, make certain that the returnUrl is actually set to a url on your site before redirecting; otherwise your page could be used by hackers to get users to visit a nefarious site.

Another option is to use the session (if available) to store information regarding what the user tried to access and redirect from the session variable.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ContainsClaim(User.Identity.Name, "role", "admin"))
    {
        //execute function 1
        Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
    }
}
```

To check if the page is on the same server:

```
var redirUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request["ReturnUrl"]);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirUrl)){
    var mappedPath = Page.MapPath(redirUrl.Trim());
    if(File.Exists(mappedPath)){
        Response.Redirect(redirUrl.Trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the redirect url as a parameter to the login redirect and pull it our to redirect back after login.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ContainsClaim(User.Identity.Name, "role", "admin"))
    {
        //get current url
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        //execute function 1
        Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx?returnurl=" + url);
    }
}
```

You can then read in this url on your login page with:

```
string returnurl = Response.QueryString("returnurl")
```

If the parameter is not empty redirect to it instead in your login method.